Filtering row with same column date value
I have a datetime field, and I want to filter the rows that has the same date value.
models.py
class EntryMonitoring(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey('Student', models.DO_NOTHING)
    clockin = models.DateTimeField()
    clockout = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

views.py
def check_attendance(request, nid):
    day = EntryMonitoring.objects.filter(
        clockout__isnull=False, '# same value', student=nid
    ).annotate(...)
    
    # do something

I wanted to add inside that filter query that clockin__date has the same value as clockout__date. Is that possible? If it is, what would be the right query to filter it?

Yes, it is possible. You should use the TruncDate function:
from django.db.models import F
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

entries = EntryMonitoring.objects.filter(
    clockout__isnull=False, student=nid, clockin__date=TruncDate(F("clockout"))
).annotate(...)
    


Oh I didn't know TruncDate could do that. Thank you!
